# Configure OpenLDAP to use organization name instead of domain component

Tags: authentication, ldap, openldap

This may be a stupid question, but I'm trying to replicate a customer's OpenLDAP configuration to test some authentication issues they are reporting with one of our applications. I haven't worked with OpenLDAP before but have dealt with MS AD/LDAP a lot in the past. I can't quite seem to get the last change to work.

This customer is using "o=My Organization,c=US" instead of "dc=myorganization,dc=com" for the authentication string format. Authentication works fine on the test server using the "dc=myorganization,dc=com" format, but how do I change it to use the organization name/country format instead? I can't find a definitive answer online anywhere for OpenLDAP and I haven't stumbled onto the answer messing around with the configuration utilities yet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object to which you refer is known as the `root suffix` or `suffix` or sometimes `prefix`. The suffix must be supported by the directory server in order to successfully process requests using that suffix or a subordinate of the suffix - at least one of the suffixes supported by the server must be `o=My Organization,c=US` (most professional-quality servers support multiple suffixes and backends) and the data must be loaded into that backend.

If you have access to the data that uses the `dc=...` suffix, change all instances of the `dc=...` suffix to `o=My Organization,c=US` in a file. Create a backend in your OpenLDAP configuration that supports `o=My Organization,c=US`, and then import your file containing LDIF (that you changed) into that backend. The details of creating a new backend with the appropriate suffix is documented at the [OpenLDAP](http://openldap.org) website.

Alternatively, a directory proxy server could be used to transform the incoming requests.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation pointed me in the right direction. Didn't realize they would have to be separate backends.